# PowerBi - Can Custom Function queries automatically refresh on PowerBi online

Tags: sql, powerbi, powerquery

Im using the following code to make a function where I can input the period then it's used to query the SQL database:

```
let

SQLSource = (Period0 as text) =>

let
Source = Sql.Database("mda", "mdamanager", [Query="DECLARE# 
(tab)@return_value int#(lf)#(lf)EXEC#(tab)@return_value = [dbo]. 
[sqSupplierBalances]#(lf)#(tab)#(tab)@Period = '"& Period0 & "',#(lf)#(tab)#        
(tab)@SupplierString = 'select SupplierID from Suppliers ',#(lf)#(tab)# 
(tab)@SelectionString = 'select * from vSupplierBalances order by  
ControlOfficeName, PortfolioName, OwnerEntityName, RegionName, PropertyName, 
PropertyManagerName, Custom1Name, Custom2Name, ServiceTypeDescription, 
AnalysisCode, SupplierName',#(lf)#(tab)#(tab)@WithCommitments = NULL,#(lf)# 
(tab)#(tab)@UserID = NULL,#(lf)#(tab)#(tab)@ExcludeInDispute = NULL,#(lf)# 
(tab)#(tab)@IncludeSupplierPropertyReference = NULL#(lf)#(lf)SELECT# 
(tab)'Return Value' = @return_value"])
in
Source

in

SQLSource
```

[image: Parameter input]

The refresh works fine in desktop for the "Invoked Function" table but the scheduled refresh does not work on PowerBi Online. I have tried numerous options, although I am new to SQL/PowerBi. Is there a work around to this?

I was thinking that since the table has the parameter previously selected in the function already stored that it should be able to automatically refresh online?

Comment: Scheduled refreshes are not supported for queries using functions. This has been submitted as an idea to the developer team and is yet to be implemented: https://ideas.powerbi.com/forums/265200-power-bi-ideas/suggestions/9312540-make-functions-refreshable-when-the-data-source-is

Answer (score 0):

I would use the Power Update Add-in:

http://poweronbi.com/power-update/

Essentially it automates the process you are doing manually in Power BI Desktop: Refresh, Save, Publish.